# What can cause react error 307 (https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

We have a rather big react application that is occasionally resulting in the following error:
https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=307

> Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.
> (https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call)

Sadly that is only happening in the production environment and we can't manage to reproduce the error in our development environment. And even in production it happens rarely, our QA department was also unable to reproduce it...

There is no obvious call of a hook outside of a function component and the component is not called outside of render return of the outer components.

Here is a extremely simplified example of the structure I'm talking about (and also a little bit of the structure of the function inside which the error happens):

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

class Outer extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Fu outerProps={this.props} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const Fu = ({outerProps}) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [boundCloseFn] = useState(() => setOpen.bind(null, false));
    //the 2nd useSetState is only used to ensure a reference to the same function is obtained for every render
    //since we only need the initial state the 'bind' happens inside a function, using the 'useState' lazy loading
    useEffect(
        () => {
            document.addEventListener('click', boundCloseFn, true);
            document.addEventListener('touchend', boundCloseFn, true);
            return () => {
                document.removeEventListener('click', boundCloseFn, true);
                document.removeEventListener('touchend', boundCloseFn, true);
            };
        },
        [boundCloseFn]
    );
    const switchOpen = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
    };
    return (
        <div onClick={switchOpen}>
            {open && <div>Stuff</div>}
            <div>Other stuff</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

We realise the creation of the `boundCloseFn` can be done with different hooks, but we don't think that is causing the issue we have.

The react error seems to happen with the extremely simple first `useState`, the very first line of the `Fu` function.

While the entire app has a lot of complicated logic and is loading some components lazily, this particular part is loaded directly, similarly to how it is in the example.

The reason we mix classes and hooks is that the class was written years ago while that component was added recently and we are trying to use hooks from now on.

Our current react version is `16.8.4`.